# Detecting click event on listview control in android

Tags: android

I have an application to be developed in android.
It has two tabs in it.
I am using tabactivity to achieve the same.
One of the tab, consist of listview so i have extended listactivity.

But now the problem is, how can i get the click event notification on listview.

At the same time , whenver there is a change event in tab,i should be notified for the same,

so how should i implement the same..

```
public class xyz extends TabActivity implements OnTabChangeListener
{
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {

 }

 public void setOnTabChangedListener(TabHost.OnTabChangeListener l)
 {
String arg0="girish";
l.onTabChanged(arg0);        
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tabchanged",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) 
  {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Tab changed1",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Rgds

Robert Sharma

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you're asking, but calling setOnItemClickListener() on your ListView should do the trick.

Similarly, for the tabs issue you should be able to call setOnTabChangedListener() on your TabHost.